# Include assignments when exporting XML from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, export, xml

When exporting XML from InDesign, I'd like assignments to show up as parent elements without manual intervention.

What I get now for a page that has three stories in two assignments:

```
<Root>
   <Story>
      <Headline>Foo</Headline>
      <Body>Bar</Body>
   </Story>
   <Story>
      <Headline>Foo2</Headline>
      <Body>Bar2</Body>
   </Story>
   <Story>
      <Headline>Foo3</Headline>
      <Body>Bar3</Body>
   </Story>
</Root>
```

What I'd like to get:

```
<Root>
   <Assignment>
      <Story>
         <Headline>Foo</Headline>
         <Body>Bar</Body>
      </Story>
      <Story>
         <Headline>Foo2</Headline>
         <Body>Bar2</Body>
      </Story>
   </Assignment>
   <Assignment>
      <Story>
         <Headline>Foo3</Headline>
         <Body>Bar3</Body>
      </Story>
   </Assignment>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this xsl on export

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Story">
    <Assignment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
    </Assignment>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```